# cmath compilation errors with clang-10 on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: mac, homebrew, xcode, macos-catalina, clang

I recently installed llvm via brew with `brew install llvm`, in order to use clang with OpenMP, on Mac OS 10.15.4 Catalina

```
$ which clang
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
$ clang -v
clang version 10.0.0 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
```

It appears I'm getting basic `cmath` errors when compiling c++ code, e.g.

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:317:9: error: no member named
      'signbit' in the global namespace
using ::signbit;
      ~~^
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:318:9: error: no member named
      'fpclassify' in the global namespace
using ::fpclassify;
      ~~^
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:319:9: error: no member named
      'isfinite' in the global namespace; did you mean 'finite'?
using ::isfinite;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/math.h:749:12: note: 
      'finite' declared here
extern int finite(double)
```

This makes me think that certain files are missing, perhaps via Xcode?

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, it seems that cmath fails to include the correct math.h.

After [applying this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59780819/5052841) , I could get the compilation working just fine, so do:

```
vim /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath.
```

#change '#include<math.h>' to

```
 #include</Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h> instead of <math.h> in
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Great catch! Your workaround is more effective than the original post, in my opinion.